# Can I put a time range in the Azure Integration Runtime alert?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azureportal, azure-monitor

I currently have an Integration Runtime alert setup that looks like:

[image]

So when the count of the runtime node is less than 1, I get an email notification. I was wondering if it was possible to add a range to this. For example: if node count < 1 for 15 minutes then send out an alert.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change the **Aggregation granularity** to **15 minutes** and the Aggregation type to **Average**.

The monitor runs every 1 minute from the time the alert rule is generated, looking at metric values for the last 15 minutes and checking if the average of those values is less than 1.

The alert rule fires an activated notification if the condition is met.

[image]